# Environment variable is not set when running a command in a supervisord script

Tags: linux, environment-variables, supervisord

My final aim is having a script always up which checks every minute if a program (chromium) is running and launch it if it's not running.
I'm using supervisord to do this, by setting in the config

```
...
[program:checkproc]
command=/home/pi/scripts/check-proc.sh
autostart=true                
autorestart=true              
environment=DISPLAY=":0"
user=root
```

The script to be launched is

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
sleep 60
if pgrep "chromium" > /dev/null
then
    #nothing
    echo "chromium running"
else
    export DISPLAY=:0
    source chromium --noerrdialogs --kiosk http://www.example.com --incognito
fi
done
```

The issue I'm encountering is that on launching chromium it fails because no display is selected, that is DISPLAY variable is not set, I guess. As you can see I set it correctly in the config (and just to try also in the script before the command).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to replace the "source" with a dot ".".

```
. chromium --noerrdialogs --kiosk http://www.example.com --incognito
```

(note the space between the dot and the command)

Adding that dot is called "sourcing" (hence the mistake perhaps?). It exports your environment variables to the subprocess you're starting.

Comment: Already tried with no luck. Anyway "source" should be equivalent to "." for bash shell.